# Can you use a jQuery AJAX $.get() request on a page that has a meta refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, meta-tags

I have a page that I need to grab data on with a jQuery AJAX $.get() request, but the page has a meta refresh tag attached to the head of the document. Will this cause the AJAX request to dysfunction?

Comment: Mete refresh? Quite outdated approach. Why don't you scedule an ajax call to refresh only the content you need? Anyway: refresh is reloading the page or an other page. The original one will be destroyed, including any pending or on-going ajax request. So it surely will disfunction on client side. On server side it depends on many things. Practucally it is not necessarely canceled.

Comment: This is a page I cannot modify the source code of, it's on a free message board service (Jcink, specifically). When you perform a search on a Jcink board you are presented with a redirect screen and this redirect screen contains the URL (with the 'searchid' parameter attached to it) needed to actually perform the search. You can see a live example here: https://cory.jcink.net/index.php?act=Search&f=

Comment: Then I don't understand your setup and problem. Do you want to fetch *from* that page with `$.get()`?

Comment: Exactly, I need to fetch the URL that contains the 'searchid' parameter in order to actually perform a successful search, but nothing seems to work and I wasn't sure if it was because of the meta refresh tag. You can view the page source to see the code, here's the line where it performs the first AJAX request that is successful (but the second one isn't): `$.get(main_url + '?act=Search&q=showuser=' + profileID + '&f=' + FBForumID + '&u=&rt=topics', function(sData) {`

Comment: The refresh is performed by the engine after parsing the html. With ajax there is no such thing. You just fetch a string. As long as it is not injected into a DOM, no refresh meta will cause problems. But: the url you are querying is most likely not in the same domain as the code that queries. This is where CORS comes in. And that might be a problem. It depends what document type you get as response. If it is json, you cound try jsonp. For plain html... I have no idea.